# Scaling UIFont size relative to screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, uifont

I'm letting users add a `UITextField` on top of their images like a caption.

I've designed it so that their images are all perfect squares according to their iPhone screen size. So on my iPhone 5S, it would be a 320x320 `UIImageView`. An iPhone 6 would be 375x375 `UIImageView`. Images posted by larger screen phones would be scaled down by the imageView when viewing in the smaller phone.

How do I setup a font size that will be relative to screen width?

I'm currently using:

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]
```

Would it be appropriate to use this?:

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.frame.size.width/20];
```

I'm not sure what point size actually represents in a font size. I've also found `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];` but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`UIFont` has a method which gets you the system font size. You can then use that to dynamically compute a reasonable font size. What is reasonable will be up to you to test and experiment with. That would lead to something like this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]*[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width/375.0];
```

Comment: Hmm, systemFontSize may vary greatly though, as it depends on the user's iOS font size setting correct? I'm not sure it would an ideal value to use. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I do however think that that it's a good setting to respect. If you don't want to do that however, just define a size which works for you as a default.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit overkill, but to get sure my text fits on the screen i am doing a loop to find out the font size (because i am rendering this text in a custom `drawRect` implementation (there might be a better way if you are using `UILabel`)

```
    float FACTOR = 0.5f;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:_maximumSize];
    // paragraph for both
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment     = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    // attributes for back
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName            : font,
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName  : paragraphStyle};
    CGSize textSize   = [_text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    // reduce font size until the text fits in bounds
    while(textSize.width > _view.bounds.size.width * FACTOR || textSize.height > _view.bounds.size.height * FACTOR)
    {
        _maximumSize--;
        font       = [font fontWithSize:_maximumSize];
        attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName            : font,
                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName  : paragraphStyle};
        textSize   = [_progressText sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    }
```

Simply adjust the `FACTOR` to make the font fit relative to the views bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4:

```
let textToFit: String = ...
let maxWidth: CGFloat = ...
var font: UIFont = ...
var textAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .font: font,
        ...
    ]

while (textToFit.size(withAttributes: textAttributes).width > maxWidth)
{
    font = font.withSize(font.pointSize - 1.0)
    textAttributes[.font] = font
}

// You have your font now!
```